# Skip loop iteration(s) interactively on keypress

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, job-control

I am looping over an array and for each iteration, run a long during process, like this:

```bsh
!#/bin/bash
arr=({1..100})
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
   echo "$i"
   sleep 10
done
```

Now I want to be able to press number keys 0-9 to kill the current process, continue and skip this number of iterations.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# set array
arr=({1..100})

# initialize skip variable
skip=0

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do

    # skip
    if [ $skip -gt 0 ]; then
        printf 'skipping %s\n' "$i"
        skip=$((skip-1))
        continue
    fi

    # run my process
    echo "$i"
    sleep 10 &
    pid=$!

    # wait for keystroke
    while [ -d /proc/$pid ]; do
        read -rsn1 -t0.1 k
        case "$k" in
            [0-9])
                skip=$k
                kill $pid &>/dev/null
                continue 2
                ;;
        esac
    done
done
```

Basically, I send the process to background and save it's pid.

Then run a loop `while` `$pid` exists and `read` keystrokes. If key is `[0-9]`, save that as `$skip` variable, `kill $pid` and `continue 2` (2 to continue the loop 2 levels up).

On every iteration, check if `$skip` variable is more than 0, subtract one and `continue` with the next iteration.

---

**Note:**

I'm not very happy with the need to set a timeout for `read` (`-t 0.1`). Maybe someone can suggest how to kill the inner `while`-loop when the process `sleep 10` finished.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32049811/5291015 possibly?

Comment: I first played around with `trap`. But I did not find out how can I skip more than one iterations from a `trap` function. And also, I want to keep my ctrl-c to kill the whole script.